# Editing file with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, edit

I have a small script to edit text in a .conf file.

```
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    rename c:\users\administrator\desktop\httpd.conf text.tmp
    for /f %%a in (text.tmp) do (
        set foo=%%a
        if !foo!=="### Section 3: Virtual Hosts" set foo="SSL Compression off"
        echo !foo! >> c:\users\administrator\desktop\httpd.conf) 
del text.tmp
```

It doesn't have the desired effect as it seems to delete quiet a lot of data from the file. Is there an alternative way I can do this?

I just need to replace ### Section 3: Virtual Hosts with SSL Compression off, whilst maintaining the integrity of the file. The current script seems to delete spaces also :(

Many thanks

Comment: Start by changing FOR line to: for /f "delims=" %%a in (text.tmp) do (

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :FindReplace "### Section 3: Virtual Hosts" "SSL Compression off" httpd.conf

exit /b 

:FindReplace <findstr> <replstr> <file>
set tmp="%temp%\tmp.txt"
If not exist %temp%\_.vbs call :MakeReplace
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%3" /s /b /a-d /on') do (
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`Findstr /mic:"%~1" "%%a"`) do (
    echo(&Echo Replacing "%~1" with "%~2" in file %%~nxa
    <%%a cscript //nologo %temp%\_.vbs "%~1" "%~2">%tmp%
    if exist %tmp% move /Y %tmp% "%%~dpnxa">nul
  )
)
del %temp%\_.vbs
exit /b

:MakeReplace
>%temp%\_.vbs echo with Wscript
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo set args=.arguments
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo .StdOut.Write _
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo Replace(.StdIn.ReadAll,args(0),args(1),1,-1,1)
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo end with
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET originalpath=.
SET originalname=%originalpath%\q20189766.txt
rename %originalname% text.tmp
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (%originalpath%\text.tmp) do (
  if "%%a"=="### Section 3: Virtual Hosts" (ECHO(SSL Compression OFF
  ) ELSE (ECHO(%%a)
 )
) >%originalname%
del %originalpath%\text.tmp
GOTO :EOF
```

I've replaced your pathname and filename with names to suit my system. You would need to replace the values assigned to `originalpath` and `originalname` to suit your system.

Note that `ECHO(` is deliberate - the <kbd>(</kbd> in this character-sequence does **NOT** affect statement-grouping.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

The search term is a regular expression but your term should work ok.

```
@echo off
type text.tmp | repl "### Section 3: Virtual Hosts" "SSL Compression off" > c:\users\administrator\desktop\httpd.conf
```